# Is there an easier/more intuitive way to model a robot for ROS then manually programming its geometry in an XML file?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I'm trying to learn how to model robots for use in ROS but the tutorials I find for creating URDF files like in both the official ROS wiki(http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)  and YouTube show modeling robots by manually editing their geometry in an XML file. Is there software for modeling the URDF robot like in CAD or at least a list of shortcuts to cut-down time for manually re-compiling XML files over and over again to move stuff into the right positions/rotations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348478/is-there-an-easier/more-intuitive-way-to-model-a-robot-for-ros-then-manually-programming-its-geometry-in-an-xml-file?/) by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there software for modeling the URDF robot like in CAD or at least a list of shortcuts to cut-down time for manually re-compiling XML files over and over again to move stuff into the right positions/rotations?

To each his own, but after you get a bit more comfortable with it, being able to simply load a text file (`xml` is essentially just text) into an editor and quickly tweak a constant (ie: length of a link, rotation of an axis) here and there is actually *really* convenient.

Note: I'm not saying there aren't legitimate use-cases for wanting to use a CAD program, but it's a rather large overhead to have to start it all up, change something, save, export, copy over, etc. @Teo Cardoso already mentioned some of the plugins for some CAD tools you could use.

Having written all of that: you could take a look at the [ROS plugin for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros). It has support for almost live preview of URDF/XACRO while you're editing it (screenshot from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/Win-RoS-Landing-Page/hiwin_case_study.html)):

[image: VSCode ROS plugin URDF preview]

You'd still be editing text, but it would cut down on the iteration that seems to be your biggest annoyance.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on 2020-04-06**:
Live compiling with VS code would defiantly make editing require alot less key-presses then what I do atm, I'll try this out!

**Comment by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on 2020-04-06**:
This works really well! XML editing changes are near instant!